# Alfresco: Workflow script fails depending on folder level

Tags: javascript, xml, workflow, alfresco, activiti

I'm trying to implement a script within my workflow definition which moves a file to a folder pre-selected by the workflow initiator. Currently, I have a cm:folder association called "vorwf_folderLink" and I am using the following code to move the file:

```
<script>      
      bpm_package.children[0].move(vorwf_folderLink.children[0].parent);
</script>
```

This works fine for higher-level folders, but if I select a folder which has no subfolders in it, I get the following error message:

> Cannot read property "parent" from undefined

Can anyone explain why this error is appearing, or suggest an alternate method to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below statement will try to get the children of the folder association which you have created.If there are no children it will throw an exception i guess.

```
vorwf_folderLink.children[0].parent
```

Instead of above just put the `vorwf_folderLink`.

Comment: Hi Krutik, thanks for the answer. It will now successfully move the document, but unfortunately it puts it into a folder one level above the directory I selected. Any pther ides?

Comment: I think you are using vorwf_folderLink.parent,you need to use vorwf_folderLink only

Comment: Yes you're right, brainfade from me! It works fine now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

bpm_package is not part of Activiti. It is part of the bridge code in Alfresco ECM that hooks the workflow engine into the ECM system.

You may be better off asking this question on the Alfresco ECM forum.